# What is it called when soldiers stick/leans to the wall before breaching?

Tags: single-word-requests

Before breaching doors, soldiers and policemen all line up on the wall near it. What is this called? Is there a even specific word for it?

I want to write something like this:

> The soldier leaned against the wall near the door and cocked his pistol and proceeded to open the door slowly as he mounted his gun against the door.

I think the first line sounds too wordy. Can you help me write it more crisply?

Comment: Your example is not idiomatic or technically correct. "To mount a gun" = "to place a piece of field artillery." I suggest, *The soldier **pressed himself** against the wall near the door and cocked his pistol. He slowly pushed open the door and directed/aimed his gun into the opening."*

Comment: Thanks man thanks for the help much appreciated. Also i did mean that he mounts his gun against the door. ie he rests his gun against the wall in order to provide support and reduce recoil. Like in COD: modern warfare 2019 https://youtu.be/ZtoO_k1bwPI

Comment: *Also i did mean that he mounts his gun against the door. ie he rests his gun against the wall* That is still wrong. You **steady** a gun against a wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term of the art for what you're describing is ***the stack***.

For instance, [this DoD photo](https://www.defense.gov/Multimedia/Photos/igphoto/2001472174/) describes what the soldiers are doing as

> Stack Formation:
> Paratroopers move along a wall in a stack formation before preparing to clear a building during Exercise Sky Soldier 16 at Chinchilla training area in Albacete, Spain, Feb. 29, 2016.

[This reference](https://primaryandsecondary.com/the-folly-of-the-four-man-stack/) weighs pros and cons of using variously sized stacks for Close Quarters Battle (CQB).

The act of forming up in this manner (typically outside of a door to a room to be entered, or along a wall before crossing a danger area) is often referred to as ***stacking up*** along the wall.

Comment: Ha i find ironic i asked this on a site called "Stack" exchange

Answer (score 2):

(Your title is asking for a word to described soldiers and policemen *all lining up*; however, your sample sentence is about a *single* soldier doing more than just leaning against a wall.)

If you want to emphasize that soldiers are behind each other, one-person deep, when facing the enemy, they are in, or getting in, (a) single file (against a wall).

**single file** (n.)

> A row of persons, animals, or things arranged one behind the other
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)

If they are basically behind one another (but not necessarily in single-file) so not everyone is facing fire initially, you can say they are

**in enfilade**

> A formation or position is "in enfilade" if weapons fire can be
> directed along its longest axis. [artsandculture.google](https://artsandculture.google.com/entity/enfilade-and-defilade/m02pqsq)

[image: Wikipedia illustration3] (Wikipedia illustration)

> Origin Early 18th century (denoting the position of a military post
> commanding the length of a line): from French, from enfiler ‘thread on
> a string, pierce from end to end’, from en- ‘in, on’ + fil ‘thread’.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enfilade)

---

> Columns approaching the gun and lines engaged from a position on their
> flanks are said to be taken **in enfilade**. Troops taken **in
> enfilade** at short ranges are ordinarily annihilated. [US
> Navy; *Landing-Force Manual*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Landing_force_Manual_United_States_Navy/8rHn1rMJ3iQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22in%20enfilade%22&pg=PA218&printsec=frontcover) (1927)

> A formation or position is “**in enfilade**” if weapons fire can be
> directed along its longest axis. For instance, a trench is enfiladed
> if the opponent can fire down the length of the trench. A column of
> marching troops is enfiladed if if fired on from the front or rear
> such that the projectiles travel the length of the columns. A rank or
> line of advancing troops is enfiladed if fired on from the side
> (flank).  [John Shively; *Profiles in Survival*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Profiles_in_Survival/1aXUAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22in%20enfilade%22&pg=PA591&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

Comment: Not exactly I meant something like this: https://www.teahub.io/viewwp/wioTwh_oil-us-army-meme/                  well now that i think of it might just be that only but idk I'm kinda confused.

Comment: That is what I had in mind. I interpret it as basically being en filade, but using the wall as cover--if the enemy pops out and fires, the bullets are coming at the troops along the long axis.